# Postman App not add cookies to request

Tags: cookies, postman, postman-collection-runner

I am using postman 6.1.3 and mac os 10.13.4.

My login request return a cookie and postman set it to cookies I can see that cookie in postman cookies part.  But all the requests after login not add that cookie . Can postman  manage all cookies?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue. I found out that I had "Inherit auth from parent" on under the request's authorization. Turning that off (no auth) populated the cookies for the request.

Answer (score 0):

I ran across your post while searching for an issue with cookies since last Postman update.
Hope this might help:
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/4581